# Python pandas .join() returns NaN in the column I joined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all I'll introduce what the post is all about.

I am learning NN from the book "Machine Learnin with SciKit and Tensorflow" - loose translation from my native language.
In the second chapter the author of this book presented a NN that predicts housing prices with regard to various inputs.

After completion of this chapter I decided I want to try to see the results on a chart and compare them to training data, but to do this I needed to convert numpy predictions array to pandas dataframe and then join the predictions with testing data.
But for some reason when I use `plot_test_data = plot_test_data.join(predicted_data_frame)`
on the converted numpy matrix the resulting column in the pandas dataframe object consists of NaN's.

The testing data consists of thousand of samples from which 5 are selected randomly, because of shuffling.

Dtypes of example of test data:

```
test_data.dtypes:
longitiude         float64
latitiude        float64
housing median age    float64
count of rooms        float64
count of bedrooms     float64
population            float64
families              float64
median earnings       float64
distance to ocean     object
dtype: object
```

And from this test data the predictions are made using SciKit linear regression model, the resulting array is a numpy array.
predictions:

```
 [ 85657.90192014 305492.60737488 152056.46122456 186095.70946094
   244550.67966089]
```

And now I am converting this array using pandas `.DataFrame()` function like this:

```
plot_test_data = test_data.drop('distance to ocean', axis=1) # since 'distance to ocean' is 
not a numerical value I drop it for plotting purposes
predicted_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(predictions.T, columns=['housing median'])
# and then I join predicted_data_frame and plot_test data:
plot_test_data = plot_test_data.join(predicted_data_frame)
```

But the resulting column in merged `predicted_data_frame` pandas objects consists of NaN's;
Even though `housing median` column consists of float64 types:

```
plot_test_data:
longitiude         float64
latitiude        float64
housing median age    float64
count of rooms        float64
count of bedrooms     float64
population            float64
families              float64
median earnings       float64
housing median        float64
dtype: object
```

I don't know how to fix this, and honestly I find it important to know how can I visualise the predictions of my future models, so they can prove usefull in whatever they'll do, and I've searched on google for similar problems but I feel like I didn't found the answer(or I did not understood it).
So I'll really apreciate Your help.

Thank you in advance :)

I tried my best to describe what the problem is about, I hope it's understandable.

Edit:
Okay, the `join()` function needs a 'key' so I did this:

```
plot_test_data = test_data.drop('distance to ocean', axis=1)
predicted_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(predictions.T, columns=['housing 
median'])
# new object meant to have the unique key for the usage of merge/join 
# func
add_to_plot_test_data = test_data[['longitiude']].copy()
# since it does not have the 'key' to proceed with join or merge
# I used concat()
add_to_plot_test_data = pd.concat([add_to_plot_test_data, 
predicted_data_frame], axis=1)
# merging two dataframes to get 'housing median' column
plot_test_data = 
plot_test_data.merge(add_to_plot_test_data,on='longitiude',how='outer')
```

But unfortunately It didn't worked at all, the result was:

```
#######
add_to_plot_test_data
#######
             longitiude        housing median
0                   NaN          85657.901920
1                   NaN         305492.607375
2                   NaN         152056.461225
3                   NaN         186095.709461
4                   NaN         244550.679661
2908            -119.04                   NaN
12655           -121.46                   NaN
14053           -117.13                   NaN
15502           -117.23                   NaN
20496           -118.70                   NaN
```

The problem is I don't know how to "join" columns to these rows.

Comment: `join` does its job by key.  Do these both have the same key value?  Is there exactly one item in `predictions` for each row in `plot_test_data`?  Maybe you just need `plot_test_data['housing median'] = predictions.T`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't knew that. 
Thanks. 
I'll try to experiment on it and when I'm done I'll tell how it went.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I know where the problem is.
But unfortunately I don't know how to fix it.
Due to the fact that test_data is beeing shuffled random 5 'values' are chosen to the set.
When I used 'pd.concat()' on the newly created object called 'add_to_test_plot_data' which is meant to have the key for the '.join()' function to work I saw this: ^(post edit)

Answer (score 0):

My original suggestion of just adding `predictions` as a column will work just fine:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [2908,12655,14053,15502,20496]
y = [-119.04,-121.46,-117.13,117.23,-118.70]
z = [85658.9,305492.6,152056.4,186095.7,244550.7]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(y,columns=['longitude'],index=x)
print(df1)
df1['housing median'] = z
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
       longitude
2908    -119.040
12655   -121.460
14053   -117.130
15502   -117.230
20496   -118.700
       longitude  housing median
2908    -119.040         85658.9
12655   -121.460        305492.6
14053   -117.130        152056.4
15502   -117.230        186095.7
20496   -118.700        244550.7
```

Comment: Thank you!
Meanwhile I was experimenting and I also found a solution, maybe not that gentle as yours, but it just works.
Thank you once again for your help.